# How to show list on DataGrid in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Recently I use WPF, I have a list obtained through Dapper.

In Windows Forms I do:

```
List<Person>list = new List<Person>();

using(var conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
{
    list = conn.Query<Person>(query).ToList();
}

datagridview = list;
```

How can I do the same thing in WPF? That is, display the contents of list on a datagridview?

Answer (score 0):

This called **binding**.

There is a good tutorial here : https://wpf-tutorial.com/en/76/le-controle-listview/listview-data-binding-et-itemtemplate/

And instead of using a List, use a **ObservableCollection**.

For example, in your situation :

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgdPersons" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="300" Height="800">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="*" Header="Name" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Actions">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Cursor="Hand"  Width="50"  Height="26"  Content="Clic for action" Margin="2" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

And the code begind :

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


ObservableCollection<Person> allPersons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
allPersons.Add(new Person() { Name = "Bryan" });
allPersons.Add(new Person() { Name = "Karen" });

InitializeComponent();

dgdChapitres.ItemsSource = allPersons;
```

Don't forget that you will need to implement INotifyPropertyChange in your Person class if you want it to be in real time updated.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `ItemsSource` property of the WPF `DataGrid` if that's the control you are using:

```
List<Person> list = new List<Person>();

using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
{
    list = conn.Query<Person>(query).ToList();
}

dataGrid.ItemsSource = list;
```

Then you will get a column for each public property of the `Person` class by default.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" />
```